# Auto-covariance of the product of deterministic and wide-sense stationary signal

Tags: autocorrelation, covariance, stationary

Anybody give me an advice how to find the auto-covariance of the product of deterministic and wide-sense stationary signal. I couldn't find how to solve this, I have looked and searched the internet, I found just 1 similar topic here so I think someone in here may solve it.

The mean and autocorrelation of $X(t)$ are $m$ and $R$, respectively, and the $X(t)$ process is wide-sense stationary. $g(t)$ is a deterministic function, $Y(t)=X(t)\cdot g(t)$ is defined.

- A. Find the mean, autocovariance and autocorrelation functions of the $Y(t)$ process.
- B. Is the $Y(t)$ process wide-sense stationary ? Explain your answer.

Comment: Should we assume you already tried to apply the definition of mean and autocorrelation to Y? What did you get?

Comment: I don't know how to relate deterministic and wide-sense signal, so I couldn't try with respect to any rule, just tried some of formulas but I did not sure about that because couldnt find even some example or theory about this.

Comment: Look for the definition of a wide-sense stationary (WSS) process. Be careful that you do not confuse it with a strict-stationary process as they are different. You'll see that many deterministic processes also have WSS properties; constant mean across all time is one of them.

Comment: Thank you, so I could use g(t) as an WSS ?

Comment: The term "deterministic process" is peculiar. All moments in a WSS are constant. Your deterministic process would be a flat line. Not very interesting . I believe that you just confused the person who asked the question

Comment: Related: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16625/autocorrelation-of-the-product-of-deterministic-and-random-signal

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a clue
$$ E\{ y \} = E\{ x g \} = E\{ x \} g 
$$

Comment: Is g(t) behave like constant in mean operator ? Could you be more spesific and please write also autocorrelation equation ?

Comment: g(t) is deterministic. E{g(t)} is g(t). Expectations of anything deterministic is just itself.  It's just like E{1} g(t).

Comment: If I had any confidence that you would understand what I wrote, I would but since you don't understand the clue I have you, I don't. I think your confusion is rooted in not understanding the difference between an ensemble  average and time average.

Comment: Could you also tell me how to find autocovariance and autocorrelation of y(t) ?